# Can you suggest me some books/articles about how female birds indicate receptivity to copulation?

Tags: zoology, ornithology, book-recommendation, literature

Where can I find informations about the topic? I need to find some examples.

I also really need this particular information: I know that many female mammals display lordosis behavior that indicate receptivity to copulation, but can birds do that or it is a peculiarity of mammals only?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid the answer will depend entirely on the species. Please [edit] your question and narrow it down. It is too broad for the site at the moment. You might want to have a look at our [help] to understand what's on topic here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I edited the question and I asked for reference if the topic is still too broad. Is it ok now?

Comment: Edited again because the question was put on hold